# How do you run pre functions when creating a new document for the first time from a model with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is quite a large schema, but I'm trying to handle validation of a list of ObjectId's myself because I don't want errors returned when the passed values are objects

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({

    // origin Id to relate states when new states are created
    thingId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'thing' },
    hash: { type: String },

    // organzational properties
    title: { type: String },
    names: { type: [String] },
    realms: { type: [String], default: ["all", "things"] },

    // values
    text: { type: String },
    number: { type: Number },
    url: { type: String },
    json: { type: {} },
    list: { type: [] },
    boolean: { type: Boolean },
    binary: { 
        data: { type: Buffer },
        // binary type .PNG .JPG for decoding if
        extension: { type: String }
    },

    // family relations | inventory of other things | child things | states
    things:     { type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'thing' }], default: [] },
    parents:    { type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'thing' }], default: [] },
    states:     { type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'thing' }], default: [] },
    properties: { type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'thing' }], default: [] }, // extendable schema support

    // ownership / privacy / access control / billing
    owner: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'entity' },
    owners: { type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'entity' }] },
    payees: { type: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'entity' }] },

    // smart contract variable/dynamic pricing
    contract: {
        type: [{
            contractType: { type: String, required: true },
            thing: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'entity', required: true },
            amount: { type: Number, required: true, default: 1 },
            multiplier: { type: Number, required: true, default: 1 },
            unit: { type: String, required: true }
        }]
    },

    // meta data
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    inception: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    age: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    lifetime: { type: Number, default: 0, min: 0, max: Infinity },
    location: { type: String },
    valueType: { type: String, enum: [
        String,
        Object,
        Number,
        Array,
        ]
    },

    // state meta data
    stateId: { type: String },
    stateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },

},{
    usePushEach: true
})

thingSchema.pre('validate', function(next){
    // custom validate passed properties, parents, things, and states to make sure they're not objects
    let validations = ['properties', 'things', 'parents', 'states']
    for(var i=0;i<validations.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<this[validations[i]].length;j++){
            console.log(this[validations[i]][j])
            console.log(i)
            console.log(j)
            if(!(this[validations[i]][j] instanceof Schema.ObjectId)){
                this[validations[i]].splice(j, 1)
                j--
            }
        }
    }
    next()
})

var thingModel = node.model('thing', thingSchema)
```

But when I run

```
let thingModelled = new thingModel(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thing)))
```

the pre hook isn't run, I can't tell if these pre hooks are only run on save functions?

Or how to get hooks run on model creations?

this is the error when running 
    new thingModel(data)

```
ValidationError: properties: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { title: 'options',
4|agoraser |     list: [ 'editing', 'edited' ],
4|agoraser |     things: [],
4|agoraser |     properties: [] } ]" at path "properties"
4|agoraser |     at new ValidationError (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:28:11)
4|agoraser |     at model.Document.invalidate (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1658:32)
4|agoraser |     at model.Document.$set (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:760:10)
4|agoraser |     at model._handleIndex (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:590:14)
4|agoraser |     at model.Document.$set (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:550:24)
4|agoraser |     at model.Document (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:77:12)
4|agoraser |     at model.Model (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:55:12)
4|agoraser |     at new model (/media/rick/hyper/Dropbox/host-root/var/www/nodes/agora/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3879:13)
```

Comment: This is not when hooks are called. [Been asked many times](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2557#issuecomment-68446889) *"Validate hooks run when you call `validate()` (or `save()`, which calls `validate()` under the hood) on a document, **not when the model is created.**"*

Comment: @NeilLunn but there is hardly discussion on how to run hooks on new document creations via new model(data)

Comment: There is no hook for "new". If you want to "validate" then you call `validate()`. That's it. The constructor is not supposed to do that. Sorry but that's just the way it is and how you are meant to use it.

Comment: ahaaaa, so I run var validatedData = thingModel.validate(data) and then use the return of that to create var newThing = new thingModel(validatedData) is that what you're saying? And then .pre('validate') hooks will be run?

Comment: No dude. You create the instance with `new` and run the validation "after". Should be pretty clear. Validation does not "return" data, it just "checks" it and then produces errors where the rules specified don't match. You wrote a validate. Do you see your function "returning data"? No? Then of course it does not return. All you need do is think.

Comment: but creating the instance with new returns an error, I can't even create the instance? See what I mean??

Comment: All I need to see is that for some unknown reason it entered your head to stringify a JavaScript object to JSON and the parse it back to a JavaScript object. Probably because the initial source is not actually a valid object and the actual problem here which is nothing to do with validation at all. It's called "getting sidetracked" . Sound of hooves usually means Horses, not Zebras ( unless you're in Africa ). Look for the more obvious reasons.

Comment: The reason is that we are saving a backup state here and if the passed thing is a mongoose document then passing it to the new instantiator won't work, you need to .toObject() it which is what .stringify does when you call it, but if the passed data isn't a mongoose document then .toObject won't work so we can't just pass thing.toObject() directly. .stringify handles both cases


can you please help me run some validation before instantiating a new document? I don't understand how to do it.. I can't even instantiate the document so how do I validate the data...?

Comment: @NeilLunn the data being passed to new model(data) is an object, and so is the field returning an error, the data is valid in the sense that it isn't a string or whatever you're talking about, but mongoose is not able to cast an array value to an array when instantiating a new document, so it seems that new model() runs some validation??

Comment: How have you still not worked this out? `thingModel.create(thing,function(err,things) {` or `this.Model.create(JSON.parse(thing),...` if `thing` is actually a 'string'. That part is unclear in your question because you are **still** rambing on about validation and not realizing it's the input that's borked. Interchange callback or promise there depending on what you are using. You cannot do `new` with an array. You would either iterate each item of the array and call new, or simply pass to `.create()` which will do that and "save" for you.

Comment: @NeilLunn this is literally the data going in: https://pastebin.com/3pCx92Xb it is a valid object, but it is erroring on the array being passed at the properties path, in the schema, the properties path is defined as type: [{type: Schema.ObjectId}] So it's expecting a list of objectId's but it gets a list of objects, so I want to run some pre hooks to modify the data so that new Model(data) doesn't return an error.
do you see what I mean?

Comment: wait, the new Model() call is producing the rejection, but it doesn't stop any functionality, and still returns a document with the parsed data but just without the properties data, hmmm.... 

don't worry

Answer (score 0):

To validate some field before `save`you can use `schemaName.path('fieldName').validate(function(value, done){....},"error message")` this signature. This method is called `pre` save and if a validation rule is violated and `save` is aborted and the `error` is returned to your `callback`.

For example if you want to create a validation for `states` so can follow this

```
thingSchema.path('states').validate(function (value, done) {
  // your logic for validation
  // value will contain the value of state field
  if(validate) {
    return done(true);
  } else {
    return done(false);
  }
}, 'Invalid state');
```

Comment: and this runs when you do var something = new somethingModel(somedata) ?

Will try it now! :D

Comment: This doesn't run when you do var something = new somethingModel(somedata) ?

And it looks like using .validate(function(value,done)) is depcrecated, you have to pass an object with the validator function defined as the function + include isAsync boolean as true

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators